# Need an advice about a stable RPC Provider (doesn't have to be free)

Tags: blockchain, nodes, infura, rpc

Need a full ETh Node, please share a good RPC provider with stable connection and not enou

Comment: [For the full list please see ethereumnodes.com](https://ethereumnodes.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Chainstack should be one of the options to consider, here's why: https://chainstack.com/why-switch-to-chainstack/

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Chainstack

Answer (score 0):

here are three good RPC providers for a full Ethereum node:

- Infura: https://infura.io/
- Alchemy: https://alchemy.com/
- QuickNode: https://www.quicknode.com/

These providers all offer stable connections and are not known to censor transactions.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Thanks.

Comment: [Infura is known to track users](https://decrypt.co/115486/infura-collect-metamask-users-ip-ethereum-addresses-after-privacy-policy-update).

Comment: The statement "are not known to censor transactions" is far from being correct, there are plenty of instances clearly proving otherwise: [1](https://www.theblock.co/post/136336/a-look-at-metamask-infura-opensea-and-the-countries-they-do-not-serve), [2](https://www.theblock.co/post/162402/infura-and-alchemy-blocking-access-to-tornado-cash)

Comment: here are some more helpful rpc providers.
Blockdaemon: https://blockdaemon.com/
Ankr: https://www.ankr.com/